# 'User' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have my User model (`AbstractBaseUser` of Django 1.5) i use email as the username to authenticate and have the following `ModelResource` for my API

```
class CartItemResource(ModelResource):
    product = fields.ForeignKey(CartItemRelatedResource, 'product', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = CartItem.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'cart_item'
        excludes = ['creation_date', 'modification_date']
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get', 'delete']
        authorization = CartAuthorization()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
```

When a GET request is made to the API, I get:

> 'User' object has no attribute 'username'

**Edit** User Model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    is_driver = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    lastOrderID = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','phone']
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

    def set_phone(self, phone):
        self.phone = phone


class CartAuthorization(Authorization):

  def read_list(self, object_list, bundle): 
      return object_list.filter(cart__user = self.user(bundle), cart__id = bundle.request.GET.get('cart_id'))
```

I have another another POST in the same resource which works:

```
def add_to_cart(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
    self.is_authenticated(request)
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback     (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py", line 195, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py", line 426, in dispatch_list
    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py", line 454, in dispatch
    self.throttle_check(request)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py", line 551, in throttle_check
    identifier = self._meta.authentication.get_identifier(request)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\authentication.py", line 283, in get_identifier
    return getattr(request.user, username_field)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 205, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Comment: Could you show your User model?

Comment: Something is hard coded to check the `username` field in a User. It needs to be updated from `user.username` to `user.get_username()`. What's in CartAuthorization?

Comment: I have edited the question with CartAuthorization

Comment: Can you also add the traceback of the error?

Comment: Traceback is not readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely when Django packages which rely on Django 1.4-like models where User object always has an `username` field. The issue is either in your own code or third party code, but the question does not has enough details to tell.

- Use a full traceback to trace these addons
- Update them if patched package is available
- If there is no patch available you need to fork and patch the third party code yourself

About Django 1.5+ user model:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

You should most likely user `id` to identify the user, not `username`

Comment: My bad i didn't add AUTH_USER_MODEL to settings, adding AUTH_USER_MODEL fixed the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, what solved it was to use `AbstractUser` instead of `AbstractBaseUser`.

Then do a proper migrations so the database has the right attribute. Your code can be okay, but you will still have the error if your database is not up to date.

I say migration but it would probably be a lot easier (or the only way) to just destroy the db and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

### AUTH_USER_MODEL = User

### add a:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```